# Validate password returns 0 rows where expected to get a 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently making a validation process to check the old password of the user but problem is I can't get it why my query returns zero rows where expected it to have 1 row. 1 more thing is that even I don't convert my password text into md5 the hashed password still get the correct answer and I don't know why it happens. here's my code so far:

```
public function validate_oldpassword($username,$password)
    {
            $this->db->select('user_salt');
            $query = $this->db->get_where('login',array('username' => $username));

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
               foreach ($query->result() as $row)
               {
                  $password2 = hash("sha256",$password.$row->user_salt);
                  $this->db->flush_cache();
                  $query = $this->db->get_where('login', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password2));

                  //return $this->db->last_query();
                  return $query->num_rows();

                  if($query->num_rows()==1){
                    return "YEHEY";
                  }else{
                    return "NO";
                  }

               }
            } 

    }
```

I also checked the query and it returns the correct query which is:

```
SELECT * FROM (`login`) WHERE `username` = 'kahel' AND `password` = 'f91d20d381426ea56e57da9ab23d0c568b8f934c3ff313e1bbf6c28a4fee758a'
```

My password is `test` salt is `XgvT7F~(CYr#*0E1^UI@xkqJ5GcAO8BHsotZpf+WQ!4&ja2y%NdelLmhPSnRw9)zDK63VMuib` and stored password is `f91d20d381426ea56e57da9ab23d0c568b8f934c3ff313e1bbf6c28a4fee758a`

what bothers me the most is that in my login page function everything works just fine. Here's my login code function:

```
public function get_login_credentials($username,$password)
    {
            $this->db->select('user_salt');
            $query = $this->db->get_where('login',array('username' => $username));

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
               foreach ($query->result() as $row)
               {
                  $password = hash("sha256",md5($password).$row->user_salt);
                  $query = $this->db->get_where('login', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
                  return $query->num_rows();
               }
            } 
    }
```

I can't really figure it out why it returns zero rows.

Comment: edited the question. sorry I'm masking my table but I always forgot to do it after posting. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the login function you are setting:

```
$password = hash("sha256",md5($password).$row->user_salt);
```

and in validate_oldpassword you are setting:

```
$password2 = hash("sha256",$password.$row->user_salt);
```

you aren't doing the md5 hash on it

Comment: Well I know it as I said above. Well I that I've missed something on my stored password.

Comment: Problem solved. I stored a non encrypted password then hashed it which is why. :) Thanks!

Comment: You are aware of the security problems of storing unencrypted passwords right?